# Workaround for "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" in ArcGIS Import data Tutorial

Tags: python, typeerror, gis, arcgis, nonetype

I'm trying to follow [this ArcGIS tutorial](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/import-data/). I'm receiving a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. This happens when I try to execute `csv_item = gis.content.add(trailhead_properties, csv_file)`. Just wondering if anyone else has encountered this error and was able to identify a workaround.

Here is the code I'm running:

```
from arcgis import GIS
import os

gis = GIS("<url>", 
          client_id=os.environ.get(token),
          verify_cert=False)

trailhead_properties = {
  "title": "Trailheads",
  "description": "Trailheads imported from CSV file",
  "tags": "LA Trailheads"
}

data_path = r".data\LA_Hub_Datasets\LA_Hub\Datasets"
csv_file = os.path.join(data_path, 'Trailheads.csv')
csv_item = gis.content.add(trailhead_properties, csv_file)
```

I have downloaded "LA_Hub_Datasets.zip" and extracted it. I had no problems reading this file as a pandas data frame.

I was also looking [at another tutorial](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/mapping-apis-and-services/data-hosting/tutorials/tools/define-a-new-feature-layer/#create-a-point-feature-layer). I received the same error when I reached the following lines of code:

```
# create the service
new_service = portal.content.create_service(
    name="My Points",
    create_params=create_params,
    tags="Beach Access,Malibu",
)
```

Comment: Please remember to show the full code _you're_ running, because that tutorial has a bunch of code that builds on each previous block, so without seeing the full code you're trying to run, we have no idea whether you're correctly following that tutorial or not.

Comment: Have you downloaded "LA_Hub_Datasets.zip" and extracted it into a path that is compatible with that specified by `csv_file`?